Sending email from hostgator service with python
I have a script setup for a discord bot that will send an email to a member if certain criteria are met. I have successfully tested this script using my personal gmail credentials, but seeing how the group has webhosting with email through hostgator I would prefer to host that email and not my personal address. When I put in the SMTP server information and email credentials from hostgator, while my script says it sent the message I never actually receive it. Here is the part of the script that actually sends the message.
def send_sms(param_dict):
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP('mail.m4dstats.net', 587)
        server.starttls()
        server.login(param_dict['email'], param_dict['passwd'])
        msg = MIMEText('Your Country on EarthEmpires is Under Attack!')
        recipient = str(param_dict['gateway_addr']).replace('{number}', param_dict['receiver'])
        print(recipient)
        msg['To'] = recipient
        msg['Subject'] = ''  
        # Send the email
        server.sendmail(param_dict['email'], recipient, msg.as_string())
        print('Message Sent Succesfully!')
    except smtplib.SMTPException as e:
        print(e)

when I replace the server address line with the one for google to
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)

And provide my gmail credentials, I get the alert to my phone within 5 seconds.

As an aside, it looks like your email code was written for an older Python version. The email module in the standard library was overhauled in Python 3.6 to be more logical, versatile, and succinct; new code should target the (no longer very) new EmailMessage API. Probably throw away this code and start over with modern code from the Python email examples documentation.

If the code works with a different server, the problem is on the server you are using, and your code is probably fine. We can't know if your server supports port 587 etc but check if they have documentation, and/or contact their support.
